# uitableview does not load on when i click

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I create a tableview and  i add two uitextview in uitableviewcell ,it works well but data does not display full data on when i load ,it load when i scroll tableview, data will show in cell .so anyone can tell me.what is the problem  , and tell me how to make flexible cell length for to textview

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *articleDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:entry.articleDate];
    txtView1 = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 320,100)];
    txtView1.text =entry.articleTitle;
    txtView1.editable = NO;
    txtView1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
    txtView1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    txtView1.delegate = self;
    txtView1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    txtView1.scrollEnabled = NO;
      int a= entry.articleSummary.length;

  if(a < 100)

   {

    txtView2 = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 100)];
    }
    else if(a <200) 
    {
       txtView2 = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 300)]; 

    }
else

{

    txtView2 = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 400)]; 
}

    txtView2.text = entry.articleSummary;
    txtView2.editable = NO;
    txtView2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];    
    txtView2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    txtView2.delegate = self;
    txtView2.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:txtView1];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:txtView2];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: When you paste code into a question, if you select it and use the "code" button (looks like `{}` in the formatting bar) it puts it in this lovely code block which makes it more readable. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `NSString` `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize`
re-sized the `UITableViewCell` height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
           heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
    CGSize textSize = {245.0, 20000.0f};
    CGSize size1 = [text1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0f] 
                     constrainedToSize:textSize 
                         lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGFloat hight = MAX(size1.height, 28);

            return hight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is not good enough. You are adding UITextView to UITableCell, it should be in block: `if (cell == nil)`. I will prefer you to use custom UITableView. You will find a tutorial [here](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-add-uiimage-and-uilabel-in-the-uitableview/) and to maintain the size of UITableCell you should use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

This code is rather sloppy. First of all, I would probably re-do this completely. You will be better off creating a custom UITableViewCell subclass instead of adding views on the fly like this.

With your current code you will come across lots of different issues, including some which it looks like you've tried to fix (incorrectly) by removing the ability of IOS to "reuse" table cells. This is going to slow down your app considerably, especially if there are quite a few rows.

So, refactor the code so that you're using a custom UITableViewCell. That's the first step.

Change your code above so that you're now using a reuse identifier, but not adding any unnecessary views on the fly (they should all be added in the custom table view cell class).

After that, you need to implement the method that @SenithilKumar suggested, this will resize the cells to fit all the text in it.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue after a day long try with reload of data, [smart load](http://www.lwxted.com/blog/2012/smart-data-loading-table-views/) of data the solution was adding  `self.window.rootViewController = navController;` in didfinishLaunching after

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];
```

happy coding.. :)